# If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are uniformly integrable then $\{f_1+f_2:f_1\in C_1, f_2\in C_2\}$ is?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be uniformly integrable collections of functions
on a measure space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$,
and let $C$ be the collection defined as
\begin{equation*}
C = \{f_1 + f_2:f_1\in C_1, f_2\in C_2\}.
\end{equation*}
How to show that $C$ is uniformly integrable?

Rogers & Williams state this (as Lemma 20.7, the proof is left as an exercise) for random variables. I presume it also holds for functions on general measure spaces.

My attempt so far,
using the definition of [uniform integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability) by Hunt:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$.
Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ are uniformly integrable,
there are integrable $g_1\geq 0$ and $g_2\geq 0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{f_1\in C_1}
\int_{|f_1| > g_1}|f_1|d\mu
<
\varepsilon
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\sup_{f_2\in C_2}
\int_{|f_2| > g_2}|f_2|d\mu
<
\varepsilon
.
\end{equation*}
Now I want to use these bounds to bound
$\sup_{f_1+f_2\in C}\int_{|f_1+f_2| > g}|f_1+f_2|d\mu$,
where I need to choose an integrable $g\geq 0$:
for any $f_1\in C_1$ and $f_2\in C_2$
and any integrable $g\geq 0$,
if $|f_1 + f_2| > g$ then
\begin{equation*}
|f_1| + |f_2| \geq |f_1 + f_2| > g,
\end{equation*}
hence
\begin{equation*}
\int_{|f_1 + f_2| > g}|f_1 + f_2|d\mu
\leq
\int_{|f_1| + |f_2| > g}|f_1|d\mu
+
\int_{|f_1| + |f_2| > g}|f_2|d\mu
.
\end{equation*}
While on the right-hand side I have integrals of $|f_1|$ and $|f_2|$ separately,
they are over the set where $|f_1| + |f_2| > g$,
which I cannot bound by integrals of
$|f_1|$ over the set $|f_1| > g_1$
respectively
$|f_2|$ over the set $|f_2| > g_2$
through some appropriate choice of $g$.

I feel like I am overlooking something.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is hard to prove this  from the definition. But it is almost trivial from Theorem 2 in your link.

Comment: @geetha290krm indeed, thanks! I managed to derive a proof using that Theorem 2 quite easily.